# Disk size issue when using Dos Dir command in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, shell, directory

I have a strange problem concerning disk size while using the Dos Dir command in Excel VBA.

I am developing a procedure within which, I need to get a directory listing of a directory with all of it's sub directories, on the same computer and save it to a text file. This piece of code will be run several times by the complete routine. The computer is a generic desktop running Windows 10. Excel is running in the C:, the directory to be listed is in the E: (an internally mounted drive) and the file is being saved to the root directory of the N: (a USB drive).

The format I am running is "Dir/s E:\'Directory Name'\ >>n:\Edir.txt"

When I run this manually in a 'Command Prompt' it works perfectly but when I try to embed it in a 'Shell' command I normally get an error message in the Command Prompt pane saying 'Not enough space on the disk'. and the text file is created but truncated at a random point in the listing.

The code line I am using is '''PID = Shell("cmd /k Dir/s E:\Directory Name\ >>N:\Edir.txt", vbNormalFocus)'''

Each of the disks used has more than 150gb free space and the complete text file comes out at about 3.3mb.

I find this very confusing, each of the drives has plenty of free space and the fact that it works every time when invoked manually and sometimes when invoked from the shell command makes it even more so. Any ideas?

R. Frankham

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the answer, although I'm unclear exactly what the why's and wherefores are. The 'Red Herring' is in the Dos error message "Not enough space on the disk".

It would appear that the real problem is the time taken to process the Dos Dir command. If I put a 10 second delay ( "Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))") to give time for the 'Dir' command to complete, it works perfectly. A bit of a nuisance because it slows execution considerably but not a great problem.

R. Frankham

Comment: Note that `cmd /k` **k**eeps the window open, while `cmd /c` **c**loses the window after executing the command. (no VBA knowledge here, but I assume there should be something like `ShellWait`, which would eliminate `Application.Wait` and manual closure)

Comment: @Stephan Thanks for the reply. it pushed me on to another line of research which has born fruit.  <br/>A simple answer appears to be to use the 'wshell' command rather than 'Shell'.  <br/>   <br/>Code  <br/>  <br/> Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1
Dim errorCode As Long


Runline = <parameters for 'dir' command

errorCode = wsh.Run("cmd /c Dir/s " & Runline, windowStyle, waitOnReturn)

If errorCode <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Program exited with error code " & errorCode & "."
End If